# Real Representations of Finite Groups.

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

I know that if $T$ is a $\mathbb{C}$-representation of a finite group $G$, then $T$ is equivalent to a unitary representation of $G$.

However, is the same true if $T$ is an $\mathbb{R}$-representation? Or is there an analogous statement I can make?

Comment: Yes, every real representation is equivalent to an orthogonal representation, and the proof is exactly the same (average an inner product over $G$).